# How to reduce spaces between bullet points in itemize?

Tags: itemize, bullets

How to reduce spaces between bullet points in itemize?

I am using itemize. I want to reduce the spacing between two lines(Two bullet points). How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\addtolength\itemsep{-4mm}
\item The first
\item The second
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

With `enumitem`: add this to your preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep}
```

or

```
\setlist[itemize]{itemsep=some length}
```

If you want it only for a specific list, write in the body of the document:

```
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep]    
\item    
...    
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: enumitem is not require `\addtolength\itemsep{-4mm}` will suffice. So accepting the other answer. Thanks

Comment: Sure, but if you change the font size, you'll have to adapt `\addtolength\itemsep}`.

Comment: Use font-size dependent units to make it font-size independent. `\ex` is the vertical unit corresponding to the current height of "x". `\baselineskip` is the vertical unit corresponding to the current line spacing.